# Error in DataPicker Format

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, datapicker

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm "

let selectedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)

UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedDate, forKey: "date")
print(selectedDate)

\\method to reload the selected time inside the viewdidLoad func

let selectedDate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "date")
example.setDate(selectedDate as! Date ?? Date(), animated: false)
```

But when I run the application it returns this error

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x108e8b4f0) to 'NSDate' (0x108e8c0d0).

I converted to HH: mm because I want to record only the time in this format, but I do not know how I'm going to handle it

Comment: You are storing the date as `String` in `UserDefaults`, so you get it back as *type '__NSCFString'* rather than *'NSDate'* and you cannot cast it to `Date`. It's unclear what you are going to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

You should be storing the Date object itself in `UserDefaults` and not its String representation. In most use cases, it makes more sense to store a `Date` object, since `Date` objects represent an absolute point in time and hence you can use them for date comparison or to convert them to local times.

Moreover, it looks like that the `setDate` function actually expects a `Date` object and not a String, hence it doesn't make sense to generate a String representation of a Date and then store that in `UserDefaults`.

```
//Save the Date object
UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.date, forKey: "date")

//Retrieve the Date object, if it cannot be retrieved, use the current Date
if let selectedDate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "date") as? Date {
    example.setDate(selectedDate, animated: false)
} else {
    example.setDate(Date(), animated: false)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Andre you save String value in `UserDefaults` and try to set `NSDate` from String. If you concern with the time only then my advice to save the date as it is in `UserDefaults` and get the `time` as formatted as per as your requirement.

**Here are the following steps for saving and retrieving Time :**

**For saving:**

```
   func datePickerChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker){

    UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.date, forKey: "date")

}
```

**For Retrieving:**

```
 func getTime(){

    let date = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "date") as! Date

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC") as TimeZone! //Set your own time zone here.

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

    print(dateFormatter.string(from: date as Date))

    example.setDate(date, animated: false)

}
```

Hope it will help you and save your time.

Comment: Why bother with all of the date <-> string conversions? Just store the actual `Date` and avoid all of the conversions.

Comment: @rmaddy yes It was lengthy conversion though, I've updated my answer.
Thank you.